# How can I know where have the user been before redirection in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

In my MVC application I need to display a certain message if the user was redirected to the page from another specific page.

For example:
I have an HomeIndex.aspx view in my HomeController, and HelpIndex.aspx view in my HelpController.
If the user pressed a link in my HelpIndex view, and was redirected to my HomeIndex view, I want to display "You came from the Help page!"

```
if(was redirected from X)
{
 //display msg
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you want to use the referer don't you?

```
Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())
```